# How to test express middleware mocha

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

```
var _ = require('lodash');

exports = function(restype, opt) {
  return function(req, res) {
    //if restype is 'send', it's sends like an api
    //else it renders something
    if (restype == 'send') {

      if (req.result.status == 'error') res.status(500).send(req.result);
      else res.send(req.result);

    } else {

            var options = _.merge(opt,req.result);
      if (req.result.status == 'error') res.render('error', options);
      else res.render(restype, options);

    }
  };
};
```

but I don't know how to set req, res, restype, and opt.
and test that it (checking when res.render or res.send is called.

Answer (score 0):

So, for larger scale testing it's useful to bring in a mocking library like Sinon.  But if you're only depending on your own code (as in this example) then you can just pass in what you need. For an incomplete (you'll need to add other methods you need) example:

```
const assert = require('assert');

describe('when restype is send', () => {
  const middleware = require('../path/to/your/file');
  function renderMock(type, opts){
      // this should not be called
      assert(false, 'RenderMock should not be called');
  }

  const request = {result: {}}; // add stuff you need there

  it ('should call res.send', () => {
     let sendWasCalled = false;
     const response = {render: renderMock, send: function(){ /* you might validate inputs here */  sendWasCalled = true; };
     middleware('send', {})(request, response);
     assert(sendWasCalled, 'res.send should have been called');
  });
});
```